# VBA Formula Instead of FormulaR1C1

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, formula

Following code works as intended. However I am trying to avoid copying the formulas in each cell inside my `FormulaArray` using `FormulaR1C1`. It slows down my data collection in my other array. Because after I collect 50,000 rows of data each time the `Worksheet Calculate` function fires it recalculates all those cells w/ the copied formulas. Is there a way to do arithmetic within VBA and not copy the formulas to the excel grid?

Goal is to use VBA to get my result and print JUST the results to `With Sheet2.Cells(NextRow, "H").Resize(, UBound(FormulaArray) + 1) Sheet2.Cells(NextRow, "H").Resize(, UBound(FormulaArray) + 1)`

`Formulas 1 thru 6` are copied over and over again in the excel grid. Maybe use `Application.Evaluate` or `Application.WorksheetFunction`? Then when the `Worksheet Calculate` fires it will not have to recalculate all those formulas (over 300k) because they are no longer in the cells only their results.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Dim keyCells As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim diff As Long
    Dim ckey As Range
    Dim FormulaArray As Variant, ValueArray As Variant
    Dim timec As String
    Dim Formula1 As String, Formula2 As String, Formula3 As String, Formula4 As String, Formula5 As String, Formula6 As String

    If Worksheets("Dashboard").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        On Error GoTo SafeExit
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Formula1 = "=IF(RC[-6]<=RC[-7],RC[-6]*RC[-3],0)"
    Formula2 = "=IF(RC[-7]>=RC[-6],RC[-7]*RC[-4],0)"
    Formula3 = "=IF(RC[-9]>RC[-7],0,IF(RC[-9]=RC[-7],0,IF(AND(RC[-2]=0,RC[-1]=0),IF(ROUND(ABS(RC[-8]-RC[-9]),2)<ROUND(ABS(RC[-7]-RC[-8]),2),RC[-8]*RC[-5],0),0)))"
    Formula4 = "=IF(RC[-10]>RC[-8],0,IF(RC[-10]=RC[-8],0,IF(AND(RC[-3]=0,RC[-2]=0),IF(ROUND(ABS(RC[-9]-RC[-8]),2)<ROUND(ABS(RC[-9]-RC[-10]),2),RC[-9]*RC[-6],0),0)))"
    Formula5 = "=RC[-4]+RC[-2]"
    Formula6 = "=RC[-4]+RC[-2]"


'BA-1
        Set keyCells = Me.Range("E3:E4")
            For i = 1 To UBound(myArr)
                Set ckey = keyCells(i, 1)
                timec = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A1").Value
                
                If ckey.Value <> myArr(i, 1) Then
                    diff = (ckey.Value - myArr(i, 1))
                    NextRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    ValueArray = Array(Me.Cells(i + 2, "A").Value, Me.Cells(i + 2, "B").Value, Me.Cells(i + 2, "C").Value, _
                            Me.Cells(i + 2, "D").Value, diff, Me.Cells(i + 2, "E").Value, timec)

                    With Sheet2.Cells(NextRow, "A").Resize(, UBound(ValueArray) + 1)
                        .Value = ValueArray
                    End With
                    
                    FormulaArray = Array(Formula1,Formula2, Formula3, Formula4, Formula5, Formula6)
                     
                    With Sheet2.Cells(NextRow, "H").Resize(, UBound(FormulaArray) + 1)
                        .FormulaR1C1 = FormulaArray
                    End With
                    
                    NextRow = NextRow + 1
                End If
            Next i
End If
SafeExit:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Call PopulateBA: 
End Sub
```

Example of Output Current State in Cells:

```
A2 = 10.00 
B2 = 9.50 
C2 = 11.00 
D2 = 5 
E2 = 2 
F2 = 200 
G2 = 4 
H2 =IF(B2<=A2,B2xE2,0) = 19 
I2 =IF(B2>=C2,B2xE2,0) = 0 
J2 =IF(A2>C2,0,IF(A2=C2,0,IF(AND(H2=0,I2=0),IF(ROUND(ABS(B2-A2),2 <ROUND(ABS(C2-B2),2),B2xE2,0),0))) = 0
K2 =IF(A2>C2,0,IF(A2=C2,0,IF(AND(H2=0,I2=0),IF(ROUND(ABS(B2-C2),2)<ROUND(ABS(B2-A2),2),B2xE2,0),0))) = 0 
L2 =H2+J2 = 19 
M2 =I2+K2 = 0
```

Example of Output Future State in Cells:

```
A2 = 10.00 
B2 = 9.50 
C2 = 11.00
D2 = 5
E2 = 2
F2 = 200 
G2 = 4 
H2 = 19 
I2 = 0
J2 = 0
K2 = 0 
L2 = 19 
M2 = 0
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want to achieve. To me this looks like you are on the wrong path to achieve it. Show us some sample data and your expected output - then it is much easier to help.

Comment: Updated w/ current state vs future state. Thank you  for comment to make my question clearer.

Comment: But why do you write the formulas again and again?

Comment: Because each time the worksheet calc fires the code iterates a new row of data collection. The code is monitoring a RTD data set. So each time the data changes it grabs those changes and creates a new row in the log and writes those formulas again. So it starts at A2 and ends at A50000 or anywhere in between.

Comment: Why don't you use a table (Insert > table) - it will expand the formulas automatically each time you add a row.

Comment: I would have the same problem using a table. The table would fill in the formulas automatically after a new row is created and then recalculate itself each time bogging down the data collection. The solution if possible is too get the formulas out of the cells and into the code. So then each time the worksheet calculate fires for recalculation there are no formulas to recalculate.

Comment: No, formulas are only recalculated If one of the related cells change. e.g. row 2 would not recalculate when row 1000 ist added

Comment: True, but I feel the Worksheet Calc event is firing a force recalculation (F9) of the entire workbook somehow.